# How to apply an adjustment 'curve' to an image using an r,g,b,a matrix?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

This will ultimately be used on the iPhone but its a general question that may be answerable in a language agnostic way

**How would you apply an adjustment curve (like in Photoshop) to an image for saturation, contrast etc?**

After looking over some c, java and actionscript libraries I figured out how to implement contrast, saturation, brightness adjustments linearly using a 5x5 matrix:

```
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
```

Where I loop over each pixel and modify the r,g,b,a value of that pixel based on the above matrix but how would I translate a 5-point bezier curve from, say, a Photoshop curves interface to changing r,g,b,a for contrast, saturation etc.  Looks like maybe something along the lines of :

```
valueWithCGAffineTransform
```

could be used?

EDIT: Upon further reflection the idea is, given a 5-point bezier curve on a 0-255 axis, how can you calculate the X value for any given Y value on the path?  You can then use this information to transform r,g,b,a values for an image.

Comment: you mean use a curve to describe the location of affected pixels or difference between their values?

Comment: +1 for a question that sounds interesting, even though most of it goes *whoosh* over my head

Comment: @www0z0k  I mean to use the curve to transform the R,G,B,A value of pixels in the image.  So given a pixel that has R=10 I could use the bezier curve to transform any value of 10 to a value of 5.

Comment: it looks like there's an easy way in actionscript: you can place your curve on a background of different color, then draw both with `BitmapData` and for every `y` you'll have to start looping with `getPixel()` through your `BitmapData` at `0, y` then `1, y` until you get the pixel of the color of your curve. However it seems to be a cheat :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And the answer is:

**Bicubic spline interpolation**

Turned out to have nothing to do w/matrices but bezier curves was close.